# Помощь с Timer'ом

Tags: java, android

Как можно повлиять на работу Таймера, если он уже запущен? Пробовал сначала его останавливать, а потом менять состояние объекта (поля) и включать заново, но приложение каршется.

---

Тут реализованы сами таймеры.

```
Timer tMercury = new Timer();
TimerTask ttMercury = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        movingMercury();
        postInvalidate();
    }
};
Timer tVenus = new Timer();
TimerTask ttVenus = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        movingVenus();
        postInvalidate();
    }
};
Timer tEarth = new Timer();
TimerTask ttEarth = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        movingEarth();
        postInvalidate();
    }
};

public void start() {
    tMercury.scheduleAtFixedRate(ttMercury, 0, speed);
    tVenus.scheduleAtFixedRate(ttVenus, 0, (long) (speed * 1.36));
    tEarth.scheduleAtFixedRate(ttEarth, 0, (long) (speed * 1.6));
}

boolean moving = true;

public void stop(){
    tMercury.cancel();
    tVenus.cancel();
    tEarth.cancel();
}
```

---

Тут запуск таймеров и кнопки, которыми нужно влиять на состояние(главное активити)

```
 btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ss.stop();
            SolarSystem.speed -= 5;
            ss.start();
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ss.moving){
                ss.stop();
                ss.moving = false;
            }
            else {
                ss.start();
                ss.moving = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Добавьте код и стек-трейс.

Comment: @post_zeew Вот. В в главной активити идет запуск таймеров, после чего делаю там кнопки. Одна кнопка, например, должна останавливать работу таймера или запускать. После остановки, запуск опять не включается.

Comment: `Timer` нельзя перезапускать. Поэтому в методе `start()` Вы должны создавать новые экземпляры: